Equivalent of magic command %connections in script
I have a Glue Notebook with a magic command at the top:
%connections my_connection_name
I want to move to a script, and would like another way of setting this connections parameter. I could not find anywhere how to do that programmatically.
Later, I have:
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)

Is there an argument to one of these that I am missing? I went through the docs but could not find any.
Note: later, I use glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog and would like to keep it that way
